# cannot establish a connection jdbc:derby database

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, connection, derby

I am getting the following error when connecting to the derby database (test1) in netbeans 8.0. please give some suggestions to fix this error.

> Unable to connect. Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/test1 using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (DERBY SQL error: SQLCODE: -1, SQLSTATE: XJ040, SQLERRMC: Failed to start database 'test1' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@631d75b9, see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XSLANDatabase at C:\Users\Chirath.netbeans-derby\test1 has an incompatible format with the current version of the software.  The database was created by or upgraded by version 10.10.).

Comment: Uh the exception seems to be pretty self-explanatory? There is a version difference between the database and your driver so update one of them to match the other?

Comment: how to update the database in the netbeans?

Comment: Before you start upgrading your database, you should first figure out why you have multiple different copies of Derby on your system. That will cause you continued confusion until you track it down.